# Book, Manga or Anime which begins on a ship and afterwards they pass a big gate into a city?

Tags: story-identification, movie, books, anime, manga

I don't remember if this was a book, manga or anime, but I recall that the story started with people on a ship (submarine?). There was a fight on the ship and later they arrived and went through a big metal gate into a city.

Inside the city they had to fight monsters (or evil people?). I remember a there was a doctor of some kind. I'm also sure that the characters had special abilities.

I was living in Germany when I saw/read this and it was probably over 5 years ago.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am looking for the name of the story. Sadly i dont know if it belongs to a book or another Type of Media. Thank you to everyone who tries to help!

Comment: I also remember that inside the city they had to fight monsters or evil people (i dont remember). And i remember a doctor of some Kind.

Comment: Any ideas when/where you might have seen/read this? How long ago? What country? Were there any fantasy/sci fi elements?

Comment: It was in germany and probably over 5 years ago. The characters had Special abilities im pretty sure.

Comment: Was there something else going on before they opened that fate? Or did they go to that place right after they got off the ship?

Answer (score 1):

*The Sea Beast* is [a 2022 CGI animated feature film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sea_Beast_(2022_film)) (very loosely adapted from [a 1926 silent film loose adaptation of Moby Dick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sea_Beast)) in which a 'ship' (with 'submarine'-like moments) passes through a metal (and stone) gate into a big medieval city. In these stories actual ships likewise pass in and out of the same gates. The fighting of both monsters and people is central to the story (and some of this occurs inside the city's ginormous sea gates, some occurs on ships). The story tells of sailors who work on special ships, and who are treated as high-skilled heroes (not sure if that counts as 'special abilities') who hunt sea monsters (who come in various sizes forms and personalities).

Below are images of both film posters:

[image: The Sea Beast 1926 film poster]   [image: The Sea Beast 2022 film poster]

Comment: Dates don't seem a good match. OP saw this 5+ years ago whereas the latest version is from 2022